# Count digits in list Racket

Tags: list, racket

I have a doubt, I'm using Racket, and I wanna count the digits of a list, but I can't. I try with length but it doesn't work as I want because

(countDigits '(4 5 6 78)) > 5

the answer has to be 5 but, i don't know how to, i have a code for count digits in a number but I don't knowhow to do it in a list.
¿How could I do it?

Comment: `(define count-digits (compose1 string-length string-append* (curry map ~a)))`

Comment: Really useful, I was completely wrong with my idea, it worked, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

```
(define (countDigits lst)
  (apply +
         (map (compose string-length number->string)
              lst)))
```

Explanation:

- For each number in the list, we convert it to a string
- Then, we obtain the length of each string - that will tell us the number of digits
- Finally, we add together all the lengths

For example:

```
(countDigits '(4 5 6 78))
=> 5
```

Comment: It was really helpful, The idea I had in mind it was completely different from this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

A more naive example that wouldn't make your professor look twice :)

Regular Recursion:

```
(define (countDigits list-of-digits)
  (cond [(empty? list-of-digits) 0]
        [else (+ 1 (countDigits (rest list-of-digits)))]))
```

Tail Recursion:

```
(define (countDigits list-of-digits sum)
  (cond [(empty? list-of-digits) sum]
        [else (countDigits (rest list-of-digits) (+ 1 sum))]))
```

Comment: it throws me an error:  +: contract violation
  expected: number?
  given: #<procedure:countDigits>
  argument position: 2nd
  other arguments...:

Comment: Haha... my bad. If you looked, in my regular recursion function I had a misplaced comma, I was just typing straight in to SO. Syntax should be right now